# Is this all I have to do for the custom domain?

Tags: pythonanywhere

I have a web dev account and am looking to run my second website on it, so I have to use a separate registered domain. Below are screenshots of the message I'm getting on the DNS setup on PythonAnywhere, and below that the DNS records for my site on my domain host site (domains.com). Is this the right setup, and am I only getting this message because I added the www CNAME an hour or two ago? If not, what do I need to change? Thanks a ton
[DNS message on Pythonanywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7trE.png)

[CNAMEs on domain.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9myo.png)

Comment: It looks fine. Is it still not working?

Comment: It was probably just taking a while to propagate -- although DNS changes are often quite quick, if the old TTL settings were high it can sometimes take as long as 24 hours.

Comment: It was probably just taking a while to propagate -- although DNS changes are often quite quick, if the old TTL settings were high it can sometimes take as long as 24 hours.